# Split Excel rows with groups of columns into one row per group

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling to write VBA code to split rows in an Excel worksheet where each row contains columns with company details, followed by 6 identical groups of columns for up to 6 products into rows:

- the company columns followed by the columns for product 1.
- the company columns followed by the columns for product 2.
- etc for all 6 products

I have several Excel workbooks each in this format, produced by a questionnaire application, where each company can submit details of up to 6 products.

The sheets have these columns:

- the first 8 columns are the company columns
- followed by 6 groups (one per product) of 13 columns per product, each with similar information as the other 5 groups.

One important rule is to add a row for a product group only if the cell in the first column of that product group is not blank. Otherwise, ignore that product group for the company (i.e. row)

Here is my current code. I thought I would start with the first group of columns then use similar logic on the others, but even the first column is way off working.

First I select all the source rows and columns, then I enter where I want the data to be output.

```
Public Enum appInputBox
    IBFormula = 0
    IBNumber = 1
    IBString = 2
    IBBoolean = 4
    IBRange = 8
    IBError = 16
    IBArray = 64
End Enum

' The first product is in column I = 9
Const FirstProductColumn As Integer = 9

' The second product is in column V = 22
' So we need to count 13 columns at a time  = 22 - 9
Const NumberOfColumnsPerProduct As Integer = 13

Sub CreateProductRows()
    Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range, Rng As Range
    Dim rowIndex As Integer
    xTitleId = "Create Product Rows"
    Set Range1 = Application.Selection
    Set Range1 = Application.InputBox("Source source range:", xTitleId, Range1.Address, Type:=IBRange)
    Set Range2 = Application.InputBox("Select range on new sheet:", xTitleId, Type:=IBRange)
    rowIndex = 0
    
    Dim RowCounter As Integer
    RowCounter = 0
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Rng In Range1.Rows
        
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(1, FirstWineColumn)) Then
            Rng.Copy
            Range2.Offset(rowIndex, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=False
            rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
        End If
        RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

What ideas do you have please?

Comment: Sounds like something that could be easily done using Power Query.  Suggest you read the Help topic for  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Then edit your question to provide additional information.  Please provide data information as Text which can by copy/pasted into a worksheet. The results information can be provided as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but a bit off in tracking exactly where the data is comming from ang going to.

Also, I'd reccomend using Range.Value rather than Copy Paste.

Here's your code, refactored

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Enum appInputBox
    IBFormula = 0
    IBNumber = 1
    IBString = 2
    IBBoolean = 4
    IBRange = 8
    IBError = 16
    IBArray = 64
End Enum

Const FirstProductColumn As Long = 9
Const NumberOfColumnsPerProduct As Long = 13
Const MaxNumberOfProducts As Long = 6 '~~ New

Sub CreateProductRows()
    Dim UserSelection As Variant
    Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range, Rng As Range
    Dim rowIndex As Long
    Dim CompanyData As Variant
    Dim col As Long
    Dim xTitleId As String
    
    xTitleId = "Create Product Rows"
    On Error Resume Next ' In case user Cancels
    Set Range1 = Application.InputBox("Source source range:", xTitleId, Application.Selection.Address, Type:=IBRange)
    If Range1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set Range2 = Application.InputBox("Select range on new sheet:", xTitleId, Type:=IBRange)
    If Range2 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    rowIndex = 1
    
    For Each Rng In Range1.Rows
        CompanyData = Rng.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, FirstProductColumn - 1).Value
        For col = FirstProductColumn To FirstProductColumn + NumberOfColumnsPerProduct * (MaxNumberOfProducts - 1) Step NumberOfColumnsPerProduct
            If Not IsEmpty(Rng.Cells(1, col)) Then
                ' Company Data
                Range2.Cells(rowIndex, 1).Resize(1, FirstProductColumn - 1).Value = CompanyData
                
                ' Product Data
                Range2.Cells(rowIndex, FirstProductColumn).Resize(1, NumberOfColumnsPerProduct).Value = Rng.Cells(1, col).Resize(1, NumberOfColumnsPerProduct).Value
                rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant @Chris. Your code worked, but did not ignore blank products. After changing just one line it does everything I need. Many thanks - I need to use it many times, so the solution is a big help.

Change:
    `If Not IsEmpty(Rng.Cells(1, col)) Then`
to:
    `If Trim(Rng.Cells(1, col).Value) <> "" Then`